# Why does UILabel update kill animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a super simple UIView animation where the origin y value fails to animate to 88 on the first try if i change the input text set in the UILabels.

The animation runs fine on the 2nd attempt. It feels like an initialization problem. Running layoutSubViews and updateConstraints is not helping. Thanks for any tips on this.

```
func previewDisplay(notifView: UIView, hdrView: UIView) {
    populateText()

    self.notifView?.frame.origin.y = 0
    self.notifView?.frame.size.height = 33
    self.notifView?.layoutSubviews()
    self.notifView?.updateConstraints()


    self.notifView = notifView
    self.closeBtn.isHidden = true
    self.notifBodyLabel.isHidden = true
    self.closeBtn.alpha = 0
    self.notifBodyLabel.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.notifView?.frame.origin.y = 88

    }, completion: nil)

}
func populateText() {

    if let info = notification?.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        // Check if value present before using it
        if let t = info["title"] {
            self.notifTitleMessageLabel.text = t
        } else {
            self.notifTitleMessageLabel.text = ""
        }
        if let b = info["body"] {
            self.notifBodyLabel.text = b
        } else {
            self.notifBodyLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is `previewDisplay` used

Comment: it is used to handle a incoming notification from a parent viewcontroller.